# What is causing this error when I call apoc.load.csv?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('FILE:///Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv',{sep:","})
```

The error is:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.csv`: Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read CSV from URL
>   file:/Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv

I am able to read from this csv file using this statement:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "FILE:///Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv" AS CSVLine  CREATE (q:car { })
```

I have already added this line to the neo4j.conf:

```
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

Comment: is this file in the import directory? it's possible APOC and neo have different root directories. Have you tried adding `/import` before the filename?

Comment: Bingo. It wants an absolute path. Now if only the documentation for apoc was sufficient...